# Routing error on Ruby on Rails 3 voting system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

All I'm trying to add is a button that, when pressed, increments an "accuracy" value by 1. I've looked at many, many, StackOverflow solutions but none of them have worked for me so far. I'm working with a colleague's code, and if it helps, most of it is taken from a Ruby on Rails textbook ("Learn Rails by Example") and may be hacked together.

my view looks like:

```
  <%= link_to 'Accurate2', :action => :vote_up, :id => @post.id%>
```

my code looks like:

```
 def vote_up
   #in posts_controller.rb
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.rate_it( 1, current_user.id ) #with "acts_as_rateable" plugin
  @post.save
```

my routing looks like:

```
resources :users do
    resources :comments
    resources :posts
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
  match "vote_up", :on => :collection
  match "vote_down", :on => :collection
end
```

the error I receive is:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/vote_up?id=1

CanCan::AccessDenied in PostsController#vote_up

You are not authorized to access this page.
Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Seems like it has something to do with the CanCan gem. Would be helpful to know how exactly you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the CanCan gem which apparently doesn't give you the necessary authorization. Check this for details:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Also, as a sidenote, I would recommend changing these:

```
match "vote_up", :on => :collection
match "vote_down", :on => :collection
```

to:

```
member do
  post "vote_up"
  post "vote_down"
end
```

and making the appropriate changes in the view:

```
<%= button_to 'Vote up', {:action => :vote_up, :id => @post.id} %>
```

The reason is that actions like these shouldn't be done with GET requests since the user may accidentally submit them multiple times by refreshing the page etc.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for pointing it out. This is the code from a colleague of mine. He installed this gem to have a distinction between users and admins.

Comment: Here `member` should be used instead of `collection`.